# Insert Text before a date and apply custom format for it

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I need to insert a text before a date, and the date must have a yymm format ([$-en-US]yymm;@) after the text (i.e. PSAAPV2003)

So far I managed to do something like this:

```
Dim r As Range
    
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then r.Value = "PSAAPV" & r.Value
    Next
```

It is partially ok because de result is PSAAPV08.03.2020. It shows the entire date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Try to name your variables to something anybody can understand (r
  doesn't mean much)
- Fully qualifying the ranges help you avoiding inconsistent results (see thisworkbook.worksheets("...).

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

```
Public Sub SetCellsFormat()

    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Adjust the name of the target sheet and the range address
    Set targetRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfSheet").Range("A1:A6")

    For Each cell In targetRange.Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Value = "PSAAPV" & Format(cell.Value, "[$-en-US]yymm")
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works